# Multiple database per application. Is this better security?

Tags: mysql, database, security, multi-tenant

I am working on a project which in my mind should only be about 1 database. However, the client insists that separating data into multiple databases would be more secure in the event of a security breach. It kinda makes sense but in the end I think that if a breach occurs, you're most likely to get everything stolen no matter how many databases you have. I guess you're protected if and only if there is no connection between your databases.

My project consists of two types of users, Basic and Paid. My client insists that the basic users should have their own database while the paid users be completely on a separate database. That means I would have to build two login tables in each of the database. The problem comes in the fact that a free user (or even a guest) is allowed to search for a paid user. Well, guess what, I'll have to connect to the paid users database in order to retrieve them. Isn't this the same as having them all in one place? And I did not even mention that users need to have addresses, images and other things associated to them (basic or paid). That is where things would get interesting in trying to enforce integrity between the two databases.

Now, back to the question. Is it more secure to have multiple databases? If yes, why would it be and what must be followed in order not to break that?

Comment: http://www.applicure.com/blog/database-security-best-practice   , i dont think multiple database will help you , this link will

Comment: it is not uncommon for clients to be morons

Comment: so here's the rub. This isn't a programming question. It is a how do you feel question. Opinion based answers. Also, you say they insist. Yet you come here to get info to rub it in their face. Really?

Comment: Not looking for info to rub it in theur face. I want to get more info, opinions to do the better decision.

Comment: but you said they insist. so now what. If you can't secure 1 database, you can't secure 10. If peeps think it requires a separate database to keep multi-tenant or multi-users secure from one another, perhaps index cards are better

Comment: They insist but we havent yet decided which route to take. We're still trying to figure stuff out.

Comment: my opinion is one database. Worth the paper not written on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is one of the most common question I've heard from business all the time. You already said totally true concerns from the point of developer view and you are right about them.

Trying to separate tables of database to different servers is NOT going to help for security. Despite that, it is going to cause integrity and synchronization problems which has higher impact than the data breach.

When attackers have an access to your application server, they will also have an access to all databases. Although encrypting of source code *-E.g Ioncube for PHP-*, ain't gonna help you. On the other hand, one single sql injection vulnerability will lead you to leak whole databases even if you are using two or three separated DB.

I believe they are trying to insists about separate database service from web server.

Comment: They actually insist in having just the data spread across multiple databases. And all the databases would be in the same webserver. I tried to explain to them that a security breach would actually leak all the databases since in the end you have to store the connection to the database in a central place. Once that is breached, your toast. They kept on telling me that it is the industry standard to do so but as far as I have searched nobody does it like that. If we talk about multi-tenant, yes they separate DBs but that's a different animal.

Comment: "a security breach would actually leak all the databases" - this is not necessarily so, and using vuln scanners, realtime anti malware systems such as ionCube24, and protecting at least some of the PHP code should always be done as a matter of course as it may buy time at the very least. However multiple DB's as you describe it sounds naive, and may even be LESS secure from the increased probability of security flaws created out of the extra complexity of coding required. Do put as strong a case as possible for the downsides of this to the client. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.